# How can I pass a function name and variadic list of arguments to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic, parameter-pack

Not a duplicate of [What is std::invoke in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680182/what-is-stdinvoke-in-c). That quesiton asks specifically about that one and only feature. This question asks about a concept which can be 100% solved withOUT that feature, and has multiple, alternative solutions, only some of which even use that feature.

---

In Python you can pass a function name and arguments list to an outer function, which calls the inner function and passes those args to it, like this:

[Passing functions with arguments to another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/803632/4561887):

```py
def perform(fun, *args):
    fun(*args)

def action1(args):
    # something

def action2(args):
    # something

perform(action1)
perform(action2, p)
perform(action3, p, r)
```

How do I do this in C++?

Comment: I searched around and didn't see where this was already well-explained. Hopefully I didn't miss an already-existing Q&A.

Comment: It's already been done [std::invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680182/what-is-stdinvoke-in-c)

Comment: @john, never heard of `std::invoke`. C++ is too large. Much to learn. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is std::invoke in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680182/what-is-stdinvoke-in-c)

Comment: @Casey, most definitely it does _not_, no. That's just a related piece of the pie. Both Q&As together make a more-complete picture.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
template <typename F, typename ...P>
void foo(F &&func, P &&... args)
{
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<P>(args)...);
}
```

If the function is called more than once, only the last call is allowed to use `std::forward`. The other calls have to be just `std::invoke(func, args...)`.

You can get rid of `std::invoke` and use `std::forward<F>(func)(std::forward<P>(args)...)` and `func(args...)` respectively, but by doing this you lose support for member pointers as "functions".

---

To return the result of the function call, just do `return std::invoke(...)`, and set the return type to `decltype(auto)` or `std::invoke_result_t<F, P...>`.

This works even when passing a function returning `void`.

---

If you want to make this SFINAE-friendly, you can use `std::invocable`:

```
template <typename F, typename ...P>
void foo(F &&func, P &&... args) requires std::invocable<F, P...>
{
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<P>(args)...);
}
```

If the function is also invoked without `forward`, add `&& std::invocable<F &, P &...>`.

---

To get the correct exception specification, add `noexcept(std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<F, P...>)` (and if the function is also invoked without `forward`, also check with `<F &, P &...>`).

Comment: Why are you specifying only rvalues to be passed to `foo()`?

Comment: @GabrielStaples This accepts lvalues too. Check out *forwarding references*.

Comment: I have to say, looking at this reminds me why C++ is such a pain in the butt to use. Don't you think there is some large benefit by just keeping things simple and readable? `innerFunc(args...);` is much easier to read and instantly understand. It has a lower barrier of entry to use and modify, if you will.

Comment: I know this is the correct answer, but I feel like a novice trying to learn this concept, will immediately stop once he/she sees `std::invoke`, `std::forward`, `&&` etc. thinking he won't understand what he's reading

Comment: HolyBlackCat, I read about _forwarding references_ (AKA _universal references_) here (https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2022/02/02/look-what-they-need/), and okay, I see they accept any type. Can you expound upon why you are using 1) references at all here--when references are heavier than just passing simple types like `int`, and 2) universal references? I still don't see the value in them in this case.

Comment: @Federico On one hand yes, but on the other I don't want to dilute the answer with an explanation of forwarding references, `std::invoke`, and such, when it was already explained multiple times elsewhere.

Comment: @GabrielStaples References let you support non-copyable types, while passing by value doesn't. I expect the compiler to optimize out the references for `int`s (and other small types) when possible. Forwarding references are necessary because you don't know beforehand what parameters the function accepts. If you use lvalue references, you're no longer able to pass rvalues, even if the passed function could accept them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right, those explanation do not belong to this answer. IMHO the perfect answer should have been divided in two parts. The first one, a basic solution, something like the answer Gabriel provided, anyone can understand that and try to use it. And then some buts to explain why a second version, yours, is a better one.

Comment: @Federico, I totally agree with you. Many C++ answers are inaccessible to understand without extensive explanation. I'm really struggling to understand all the nuances of how this is better myself, and it's discouraging.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I'll try to add more details later. I suggest testing this (and your) approach with functions with different references as parameter types: `void f1(int)`, `void f2(int &)`, `void f3(int &&)`.

Answer (score 1):

### How to use variadic templates (parameter packs) in C++ to pass a variadic list of arguments to a sub-function

Although you can do this in both C and C++ using [variadic functions with `va_list`, `va_start()`, `va_arg()`, and `va_end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic), it is much cleaner and easier to do it in C++ using [variadic templates (parameter packs)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead.

The secret is to allow a generic function to be passed in, of any format, via `typename FuncType`, and to allow a variadic list of arguments to be passed in via `typename... FuncArgs`. The template specifier will therefore be `template<typename FuncType, typename... FuncArgs>`. You then pass the function name to the outer function as `FuncType innerFunc`, and you pass the list of variadic arguments to the outer function as `FuncArgs... args`. Inside the template function, the list of arguments can then be passed to a subfunction as `args...`, like this: `innerFunc(args...);`.

Here is the whole thing in context:

```cpp
// INNER FUNCTIONS TO PASS TO AN OUTER FUNCTION

void print1(int i)
{
    printf("print1: %i\n", i);
}

void print2(double d, int i)
{
    printf("print2: %f, %i\n", d, i);
}

void print3(int i, double d, const std::string& str)
{
    printf("print3: %i, %f, %s\n", i, d, str.c_str());
}


// OUTER FUNCTION

template<typename FuncType, typename... FuncArgs>
void OuterFunc(FuncType innerFunc, FuncArgs... args)
{
    printf("OuterFunc start.\n");

    // Call the inner function with all passed-in args!
    printf("Calling inner function with all passed-in args.\n");
    innerFunc(args...);

    printf("OuterFunc end.\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    OuterFunc(print1, 100);
    OuterFunc(print2, 99.1234, 77);
    OuterFunc(print3, 123, 10.55, "hey you!");

    return 0;
}
```

Full, runnable example, with comments:

[variadic_templates_parameter_packs_and_functions.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/variadic_templates_parameter_packs_and_functions.cpp) from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```cpp
// C++ includes
#include <cstdint>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <cstdio>   // For `printf()`
#include <iostream>  // For `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::endl`, etc.
#include <string>


// -------------------- Some inner functions to choose from START -------------------

void print1(int i)
{
    printf("print1: %i\n", i);
}

void print2(double d, int i)
{
    printf("print2: %f, %i\n", d, i);
}

void print3(int i, double d, const std::string& str)
{
    printf("print3: %i, %f, %s\n", i, d, str.c_str());
}

// -------------------- Some inner functions to choose from END ---------------------

// The outer function, which is a variadic template, containing one `typename...` parameter pack.
// See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack
template<typename FuncType, typename... FuncArgs>
void OuterFunc(FuncType innerFunc, FuncArgs... args)
{
    printf("OuterFunc start.\n");

    // Call the inner function with all passed-in args!
    printf("Calling inner function with all passed-in args.\n");
    // See the "Expansion loci" section of this documentation here:
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack
    // This is really cool, because calling the inner function like this is **just like the Python
    // example here!**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/803632/4561887--except you pass the arguments
    // to the inner function as `args...` in C++ here instead of as `*args` (the contents of the
    // arguments list) in Python.
    innerFunc(args...);

    printf("OuterFunc end.\n\n");
}

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("Demonstrate variadic templates (parameter packs) in C++!\n\n");

    OuterFunc(print1, 100);
    OuterFunc(print2, 99.1234, 77);
    OuterFunc(print3, 123, 10.55, "hey you!");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample build and run command, and output:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/cpp$ time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 variadic_templates_parameter_packs_and_functions.cpp -o bin/a && bin/a

real    0m0.281s
user    0m0.245s
sys 0m0.036s
Demonstrate variadic templates (parameter packs) in C++!

OuterFunc start.
Calling inner function with all passed-in args.
print1: 100
OuterFunc end.

OuterFunc start.
Calling inner function with all passed-in args.
print2: 99.123400, 77
OuterFunc end.

OuterFunc start.
Calling inner function with all passed-in args.
print3: 123, 10.550000, hey you!
OuterFunc end.
```

### References

1. [Multiple typename arguments in c++ template? (variadic templates)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19923558/4561887)
2. [cppreference.com: variadic templates (parameter packs)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: This would benefit from perfect forwarding: `FuncType &&innerFunc, FuncArgs &&... args`, then `std::forward<FuncType>(innerFunc)(std::forward<FuncArgs>(args)...)`, or perhaps even `std::invoke(std::forward<FuncType>(innerFunc), std::forward<FuncArgs>(args)...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can create template class to pass function pointer. Here is my example to call both free function and class method.

```
template<typename T>
class Invoker;

template<class C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
class Invoker<Ret (C::*)(Args...)>
{
public:
    Ret Invoke(Ret(C::*method)(Args...), C* instance, Args... args) {
        return std::invoke(method, instance, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
class Invoker<Ret(Args...)>
{
public:
    Ret Invoke(Ret(method)(Args...), Args... args) {
        return std::invoke(method, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

// use



void foo(int a) {
    cout << __FUNCTION__  << a << endl;
}

int bar() {
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;
    return 42;
}

class Foo {
public:
    void foo(int a) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__  << a << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Invoker<decltype(&Foo::foo)> inv;
    inv.Invoke(&Foo::foo, &f, 10);

    Invoker<decltype(foo)> inv2;
    inv2.Invoke(&foo, 5);

    Invoker<decltype(bar)> inv3;
    inv3.Invoke(&bar);    
    
    return 0;
}
```